# TortoiseSVN - Diff ignore comments - Regex filter

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, diff

I'd like to be able to ignore changes (in particularly, deletes ) of comment lines...

First issue, the "ignore comments" button in the TortoiseSVN diff view is grey'd out.

Second issue, the language I'm working allows for "non-standard" comments.  Specifically, an asterick in column 7 indicates a comment line.  I don't see any method of configuring what Tortoise consider's a comment.

That being the case, I thought the regex filter might be an option.  However, that doesn't seem to prevent deleted comment lines from showing as a change.

Am I doing something wrong?  Or is that just a limit of the built-in diff viewer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whats the problem here, as I can't find an "Ignore comments" button at all.
But as Tortoise mentions in their docu you can just use normal RegularExpressions to ignore user-defined literals:

[Regex Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcA5s.png)

- The simplest hack is to just ignore comments lead by a hash:
  `#.*`
- normal C/Java-Style Comments:
  `//.*`
- for your specific case, simply type in 6 spaces before `\*.*`
  or do this: `\s{6}\*.*`

---

Another solution would be to edit a properties file for Tortoise-SVN. The file you are searching for is located at `%appdata%\TortoiseSVN\ignorecomments.txt`

There you can add a comment style for any file extension you prefer. Let's say, your file extension is `xyz`, then you will have to append following line to the `ignorecomments.txt` file:

```
xyz=      *,
```

Note the comma at the end of the line, that indicates the start of a comment.

From now on, when you click the "ignore comments" button in the diff viewer, your comments will be ignored.

Comment: As mentioned in the OP...regex worked, except for deleted comments showing as a changed lined...

Comment: I found a solution using the _ignorecomments.txt_ file. Maybe that is what you searched for

Comment: actually we've moved from SVN to Git, but i am using TortoiseGit which has the same ignorecomments.txt file.  Do you know the format of the expressions used in it?

Comment: No sorry, I just have TortoiseSVN at work. But I'd guess that TortoiseGit uses the same patterns? Do you have prefilled patterns? My *ignorecomments.txt* already gave me a few lines.